# Issue to use CLI commands to manage RabbitMQ Message broker on Openshift

Tags: rabbitmq, openshift

My image of rabbitmq in openshift is deployed and works perfectly fine.
I manage this image in the Openshift web tool.
However, when I want to use some administration CLI tools like rabbitmqctl to manage the node ( https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html ), I get the following error :

‘Only root or rabbitmq should run rabbitmqctl’

I tried :

- To add the permission to modify the rabbitmq server files to the root group, which is not permitted : 
  $ chgrp -R 0 /var/lib/rabbitmq chgrp: changing group of '/var/lib/rabbitmq': Operation not permitted
- To connect as root in the container, but I cant.

The rabbitmq-plugins command actually works, I can enable the different plugins with the CLI tool.

Any Idea?

Comment: Hi, this question is not programming related, per se. You might find more help from https://superuser.com/. Having said that: Did you try sudo?

Comment: I don't have access to the sudo command unfortunately. I wonder if I should change the dockerfile of my image to change the rights needed to use rabbitmqctl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update - I found a solution here :

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/creating_images/guidelines.html#openshift-specific-guidelines

I need to modify my dockerfile, as described in the link.